# if i have different asp.net checkboxes in webform with different text as 450, 550, 500, 900

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have different checkboxes in vb.net webform with different text ...

```
checkbox1.text=100
checkbox2.text=300
checkbox3.text=550 and so on .....
```

i want when i check checkbox1 and checkbox2 then in textbox1 the text would be 400

means as many as checkbox i select the sun of checkboxes selected will be calculated in textbox using VB.NET ....

i m using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at server side code then following code should do the trick:

```
private int mTotal;

private void EnumerateCheckBoxes(Control control)
{
   if (control is CheckBox)
   {
     var check = (CheckBox)control;
     if (check.Checked)
     {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(check.Text, out value))
        {
          mTotal += value;
        }
     }
   }
   else if (control.HasControls())
   {
     foreach(var c in control.Controls) 
     {
       EnumerateCheckBoxes(c);
     }
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mTotal = 0;
   EnumerateCheckBoxes(this.Form);
   textbox1.Text = mTotal.ToString();
}
```

Although, this is in C#, it should be easy to port to VB.NET. Also few other things to consider:

1. This code will count radio buttons
   as well as because it gets inherited
   from CheckBox. If that is to be
   avoided then replace `if (control is
   CheckBox)` with `if
   (control.GetType() ==
   typeof(CheckBox))`
2. If you wish to consider checkboxes
   from CheckBoxList then you have to
   write another condition to see if
   control is CheckBoxList and then
   within condition, enumerate items
   withing checkboxlist. Items count to
   be added to total count while
   selected items to be added to
   checked count.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field and a bit of javascript to set the value, bind this event when a checkbox is checked

```
function UpdateValue(){
var total= 0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    val = total+ int.parse(this.value); //or html
});
   $('#hiddenValField').html(total) ;
}
```